# Getting data from database using keys

Tags: php

I'm setting up a small database for a project, in which I'm trying to get data from a database using keys. The idea is that the user gets a certain key, in this case, 6 random digits, and enters this into a search box. After clicking submit this will give the user a query with the data connected to the key.

I know I have to work using PHP, submit forms and such. But it's been awhile since I worked with databases.

I wouldn't need a whole working piece of code, but more some help in how to tackle this problem. I googled this but couldn't find what I looked for.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Sem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below a simple example.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['query'])) {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=yourdb;host=localhost', 'username', 'password');

    $query = $_POST['query'];

    $sth = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE name LIKE :query');
    $sth->execute(
        array(
            'query' => '%' . $query . '%',
        )
    );

    $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} else {
    echo '<form method="post"><input type="text" name="query"><button type="submit"></form>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Did some tweaking to make it fit the code i already had. it works now.